# Logic: Translate the following into everyday English

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic, quantifiers, logic-translation

> Translate the following into everyday English. Note that everyday English does not use variables.
>
> In the following wfs $A^1(x)$ means $x$ is a person, $A^2(x,y)$ means $x$ hates $y$.

$i)\exists x (A^1(x)\land\forall y (A^1(y)\to A^2(x,y)))$

$ii)\forall x(A^1(x)\to\forall y(A^1(y)\to A^2(x,y)))$

$iii)\exists x (A^1(x)\land\forall y(A^1(y)\to(A^2(x,y)\leftrightarrow A^2(y,y))))$

I did i)

i) For every person, there exist another person such that the second hates the first person.

Is it correct?

Also note that I first translate the proposition inside $\forall y (A^1(y)\to A^2(x,y))$

How do I translate $ii)$ and $iii)$?

This is very difficult help please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your (i) is incorrect.

Try writing out the definitions of the symbols $\exists$,$\forall$,$\implies$, $A^1$,$A^2$ then simplifying the English.

(i) reads "there exists $x$ such that $x$ is a person and for every $y$, $y$ being a person implies $x$ hates $y$.

More simply this is just "some dude $x$ hates all people"

Try the other two by first writing out the literal meanings then simplifying.

Comment: Everyday english doesn't use variables and you used variables in $i)$ (x andy), why?

Comment: Sure it does! Someone's name might be $x$.  If you'd like, you could remove it to get "there exists a person who hates all people". Or even more simply, "someone hates everyone".

Comment: ok, I translate ii) but I get confused when I try to simplify, "For every $x, x$ being a person implies that for every $y, y$ being a person implies that x hates $y$"

Comment: First simplify the second part "for every y, y being a person implies x hates y", so x hates all people.  Thus the statement becomes "For every x, x being a person implies x hates all people".  Can you get the last step?

Comment: "everyone hates everyone" or "everyone hates all people"?

Comment: Yep! Both of those statements work.